# Compare two int arrays of different size in O(N * log(N)) time?

Tags: c, arrays, comparison

I need to compare between two int arrays of different size.

It has to be most efficient.

Is it possible to do in O(N * log(N)) time?

It should print integers that differ between the two arrays.

Comment: Arrays decay to pointers when passed as arguments to a function, so you need an explicit `size` parameter if you don't want Bad Things to happen.

Comment: So, what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: i dont know how to compare between 2 dffrent size arrays one is bigger then the other and i dont know where and how to stop comparing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm is O(n), but you are assuming that the arrays are equally sized and each one has a size of `ARY_SIZE`.

I will not solve the entire homework for you, but I suggest you start with the following function header: `int compar2arr(int arrA[], int arrA_size, int arrB[], int arrB_size)`.

Keep in mind that for function arguments `int arrA[]` is merely equivalent to `int* arrA`.

As noted by Keith and Sebastian, `arrA_size != arrB_size` implies different (unless an author of the task defines it in other way). So you check it at the begining and return `false` if it holds.

**EDIT**

Ok, I re-read your post and it seems you need to just display all the not-equal elements and you do not know how to deal with the fact they are of different sizes.

Therefore I suggest to start with the following:

```
int compar2arr(int arrA[], int arrA_size, int arrB[], int arrB_size)
{
   int smaller_size = // arrA_size or arrB size, the smaller one; 
   int higher_size = // arrA_size or arrB size, the higher one; 
   int *bigger_array;  
   int i;     
   int result = true;

   if (arrA_size > arrB_size)
       bigger_array = arrA;
   else
       bigger_array = arrB;

   for (i = 0; i < smaller_size; i++)
   {
      if (/* i-th elements are not(!!) equal */)
      {
         result = false;
         // print the values to be different
      }
   }

   if (smaller_size != higher_size)
     result = false;

   for (i = smaller_size; i < higher_size; i++)
   {
       // print bigger_array[i]
   }

   return result;
}
```

I am sure you can come up with the actual code to replace comments.
It is not the most concise way to write, but wanted to keep it easy to understand. Anyway, the computational complexity is O(n), the best possible.

Comment: its not homework its before test:( i know my code is bad but i dont know where and how to stop comparing because one array is bigger than the other

Comment: If their sizes are different, they're different; compare their sizes first and don't bother comparing elements if they differ.  (I'm making an assumption about your definition of "different"; if that assumption is incorrect, you'll need to tell us.)

Comment: i misread the question:( it has to be O(nlogn):((((

Comment: what do i need to change in order to make nlogn?

Comment: `n * logn` is worse than `n`. What is the point in getting worse result than possible? I suspect you have misunderstood your task and mis-conduced it to us.

Comment: the question in the book ask for nlogn

Comment: If it is in O(n) it is in O(nlogn).

Comment: True, but typically you specify the "smallest" bounding function.

Answer (score 1):

If both arrays are differently sized, then they are already different, no need to compare content, just size.

Comment: they are not sorted an i need to print only the diffrent elements

Answer (score 1):

If you need to print only the different elements, then it is not possible in 0(n) time. The best way to solve your problem would be to sort the two arrays (using qsort) and then loop from zero to the smaller of the two array sizes.

Additionally, you cannot break when you get to the first different integer if you are trying to print all of the mismatching integers. What you want to do is print out "%d doesn't match %d at index %d" or something similar each time you find a mismatching element.

Finally, if the size aren't equal, I would loop over the last section of the longer array and print out the extra elements.

Comment: i NEED NLOGN - i was mistaken

Comment: qsort is nlogn, and you don't have to implement it. look at qsort's mang page: http://linux.die.net/man/3/qsort